# Using Julia to open a JSON file that is located at a particular directory

Tags: julia

Suppose there is a JSON file at a particular location. Let's say at "C:\Data\". Using Julia, how do I load the file, so that I may use its content for analysis?

The following link provides access to a sample of my JSON files. For the readers information, I am in the process of learning how to extract market data from Betfair.

Link: [Betfair JSON File Example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5y07itzcsmugwpr/1.122430932?dl=0)

Answer (score 10):

You just specify the full path to the file to the JSON parser you are working with. For example with the [`JSON`](https://juliahub.com/ui/Packages/JSON/uf6oy/0.21.0) package:

```
julia> using JSON

julia> JSON.parsefile("/Users/fredrik/test.json") # full path
Dict{String,Any} with 2 entries:
  "hello" => 1
  "world" => Any[1, 2]
```

If you are running the code in the same directory as the JSON file you can just use the filename since Julia defaults to look in the current directory:

```
julia> JSON.parsefile("test.json") # relative path
Dict{String,Any} with 2 entries:
  "hello" => 1
  "world" => Any[1, 2]
```

Comment: Can I ask you to try the file I linked to? I get the error 
Expected end of input
Line: 1
Around: ...rer"}}]} {"op":"mcm","clk":"18...